# How to use JQuery to get data from multiple drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get car information from a car selling website, and I'm trying to achieve that by directly write a script in Chrome.

And the website uses "selected-model" and "un-selected-model" to store selected value and unselected item list. And only when you choose one, the next one would show up.

[image: like this]

There are three pull-down menu list this and I want to get data formatted in order, like which year has what make has what model...

```
<span id="selected-model" class="name" value=""></span>
    <ul class="drop" id="un-selected-model"></ul>
</div>
```

I'm so struggled and I'm not quite familiar with JQuery.

Comment: can you post your script code and expected output ?? not enough detail